# VS2010 and VS2008 together won't run properly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have VS2008 and VS2010 installed on my machine. Both works fine when there is only one IDE is running i.e. Vs2010 works fine when there is no Vs2008 instance opened and vice versa. 
When I run application from VS2008/2010 in debug mode I get below error message

> Unable to connect to Asp.net development server.

Even doing iisreset doesn't solve this, I need to restart my machine and then work on only one IDE at a time. My development machine has win7 & IIS7.

Comment: `Asp.net development server` is not IIS - it is Cassini, the development web server that is bundled with VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDEs are probably trying to use the same port.  Check the icons of the Development servers in the notification area to see what port each of them is using.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx) gives details about how to change it.